# Bit checking in two's complement implemented only with subtraction and branch if less than zero

Tags: bit-manipulation, subtraction

In two's complement representation, using only subtraction and "branch if less than zero" I am supposed to implement bit checking. No straightforward logical operations are allowed, unless they are implemented with these two instructions.

So lets say than I have an integer x such as `b(n-1) b(n-2) ... b(i) ... b(2) b(1) b(0)` where (i) indicates the i-th bit of the n-bit number.

I want to find a number y to subtract from x that gives the results:

- x-y >= 0 if b(i) = 1
- x-y < 0 if b(i) = 0

I have been banging my head for a couple of days now, and as a last result I came here for a couple of ideas/tips.

Comment: This is not a practical problem. It looks more like a puzzle. Any modern programming language will support bit operations.

Comment: If x >= 2**n then x =x - n, idem for n-1, n-2 etc. Once at i, if x>=2**i, b(i) is set otherwise it is not.

Comment: I am working on a hypothetical one-instruction computer, I just made things simple so others can understand.

Comment: @Tolis does my suggestion not work (it only uses comparisons and subtractions)?

Comment: @assylias By 2**n do you mean 2 to the power of n? (My last response was to Raymond Chen.)

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. You basically set all the bits between i+1 and n to 0 and then check if what's left is great than 2 to the power of i or not.

Comment: The solution is supposed to have a complexity that is linear to n.

Comment: @assylias Thanks for the help, by using yor algorithm and by using a temporary value you can "mirror" the bits of x. So you get an integer temp such as
b(0) b(1) ... b(i) ... b(n-3) b(n-2) b(n-1). We are in two's complement so if temp is less than zero that means that b(0) is equal to 1. We then can shift temp to the left by doing
temp = temp -(-temp). We continue n times.

Comment: I still dont know if it is an acceptable answer to what exactly I was asked to do, but it is a start.

Comment: Hypothetical one-instruction computers are off topic for  StackOverflow, which according to the FAQ is for solving practical programming problems.